# LegendreQ[2,z] formula on functions.wolfram.com unequals result from Mathematica

Tags: special-functions

The formula for `LegendreQ[2,z]` on [this functions.wolfram.com page](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LegendreQGeneral/03/01/02/0014/) gives:

```
Expand[(1/2) (Log[1 + z] - Log[1 - z]) LegendreP[2, z] + Sum[((4 - 4 k - 1)/((2 k + 1) (2 - k))) LegendreP[2 - 2 k - 1, z], {k, 0, Floor[(2 - 1)/2]}]]
```

which can be evaluated to:

```
(3 z)/2 + 1/4 Log[1 - z] - 3/4 z^2 Log[1 - z] - 1/4 Log[1 + z] + 
3/4 z^2 Log[1 + z]
```

whereas `Expand[LegendreQ[2,z]]` directly evaluated gives:

```
-((3 z)/2) + 1/4 Log[1 - z] - 3/4 z^2 Log[1 - z] - 1/4 Log[1 + z] + 
3/4 z^2 Log[1 + z]
```

I assumed that both results are the same, but Mathematica gives a different sign for the `((3 z)/2)` term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an error on the Wolfram Functions page. (Please report it to `comments(AT)functions(DOT)wolfram(DOT)com`.)

The correct formula is

$$Q_n(z)=\frac12\left(\log(1+z)-\log(1-z)\right)P_n(z)\color{red}{-}\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor}\frac{2n-4k-1}{(2k+1)(n-k)}P_{n-2k-1}(z)$$

or, in *Mathematica* format,

```
LegendreQ[n, z] == (1/2) (Log[1 + z] - Log[1 - z]) LegendreP[n, z] - 
Sum[((2 n - 4 k - 1)/((2 k + 1) (n - k))) LegendreP[n - 2 k - 1, z],
    {k, 0, Floor[(n - 1)/2]}]
```

Comment: I assume, had the error been in M's result, there wouldn't be close votes? At the same time, this answer reaffirming M's correct behavior seems necessary. Now I can't make up my mind.

Comment: Not really sure. I certainly didn't vote to close since my vote is instantly fatal. Nevertheless, I think this is a good example on how to use *Mathematica* to verify any formula you've found on the Internet.